# Not able to come back to my app from Instagram after sharing photo using iPhone hooks

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I want to share/post photo on Instagram from my app and I could do it using iPhone hooks which opens Instagram app.

But I couldn't find way to come back to my app after sharing photo.

Let me know if it is supported by Instagram. If not then please suggest alternative way for same.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported with the instagram app, but in IOS 9 they introduced a button on the left of the status bar which says "back to.." to go back to whatever app opened this one. A rather nice unpublicised addition if you ask me

Comment: Thanks Andy. :) Do you have any suggestions on how to do it on iOS 8?

Comment: I don't unfortunately. When testing I've just been double tapping the home button and using the OS's multitasking to do it. Not ideal. I know for example that when posting to facebook, facebook returns to your app with the post ID. Thats what I was hoping for with Instagram